# c# Split sentence

Tags: c#, string

Is it possible to split this combined words into two?
ex: "Firstname" to 
"First"
"Name"

I have a bunch of properties eg FirstName,LastName etc. and I need to display this on my page. Thats why I need to separate this property name to display into more appropriate way.

Comment: It is possible but you will have to explain the algorithm. I mean what's the logic? How would you split the following input `Ddjkfhsdks` for example? You see without a clear problem description you cannot write a clear function.

Comment: *only that word*? If so, then `s.Substring(0, 5)` and `s.Substring(5, 4)` would do, or just: `string s1 = "First"; string s2 = "Name";` You need to be more specific about what you want to do.

Comment: Does any part of the word have a fixed length?

Comment: Sorry guys, I have a bunch of properties eg FirstName,LastName etc. and I need to display this on my page. Thats why I need to separate this property name to display into more appropriate way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a dictionary of all 'single' words the only solution I can think of is to split on upper letters:

FirstName -> First Name

The problem will still exist for UIFilter -> UI Filter.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** OP specified that he needs to split property names

If you follow CamelCase naming convention for properties (i.e. "FirstName" instead of "Firstname"), you can split the words by upper case characters quite easily.

```
string[] SplitByCaps(string input)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = input[i];
        if (i > 0 && Char.IsUpper(c))
            output.Append(' ');

        output.Append(c);
    }
    return output.ToString().Split(' ');         
}
```

**Orinal answer:**

I would say, for **practical** purposes, it's not possible to do this for any arbitrary string.

Of course it is possible to write a program to do this, but whatever your actual needs are, that program would be overkill. There might also be libraries that already do this, but they would be so heavy that you wouldn't want to take a dependency on them.

Any program which could achieve this would have to have know all words in the English language (let's not even consider multilanguage solutions). You would also require an intelligent lexical parser, because for any word, there might be more than one possible way to split it.

I suggest you look into some other way to solve your particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your aim is fuzzy.
If properties alway have Uppercase letter, you can find positions of all uppercase letters in the word and devide it by that positions.
If uppercase letters is not guaranteed, the best way would be to create transform table. The table would be define pairs of initial property name and resulting text. In this way you will have simple map for transormation

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)** to get the first 5 characters from the string. Then **[replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)** the first five characters in original string to blank.

```
string str = "Firstname";
string firstPart = str.Substring(0,5); // "First"
string secondPart = str.replace(firstPart,""); // "name"
```

If you want to make it generic for any word to be split, then you need to have some definite criteria on which you can divide the word into parts. Without definite criteria, it is not possible to split the string as expected by you.